# copy listview subitems to variable

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I've already search for any solutions but I just couldn't find one. I've found several post in several websites/forum that discusses my problem, but I want a very simple solution.

```
while (SQLDataReader.Read())
                {
                    var view = new GridView();
                    view.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn { Header = "User", DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("User") });
                    view.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn { Header = "hostNamedb", DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("hostNamedb") });
                    view.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn { Header = "fullName", DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("fullName") });
                    view.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn { Header = "location", DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("location") });
                    view.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn { Header = "department", DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("department") });
                    view.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn { Header = "position", DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("postion") });
                    view.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn { Header = "message", DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("message") });
                    view.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn { Header = "status", DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("status") });
                    view.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn { Header = "ip", DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("ip") });

                    ListView2.View = view;
                    ListView2.Items.Add(new
                    {
                        User = SQLDataReader["User"].ToString(),
                        hostNamedb = SQLDataReader["hostNamedb"].ToString(),
                        fullName = SQLDataReader["fullName"].ToString(),
                        location = SQLDataReader["location"].ToString(),
                        department = SQLDataReader["department"].ToString(),
                        position = SQLDataReader["position"].ToString(),
                        message = SQLDataReader["message"].ToString(),
                        status = SQLDataReader["status"].ToString(),
                        ip = SQLDataReader["ip"].ToString(),
                    });
                }


                userName_click = System.Convert.ToString(ListView2.Items[var2].User.Text.ToString());
                hostName_click = System.Convert.ToString(ListView2.Items[var2].hostNamedb.Text.ToString());
                fullName_form = System.Convert.ToString(ListView2.Items[var2].SubItems[2].Text.ToString());
                location_form = System.Convert.ToString(ListView2.Items[var2].SubItems[3].Text.ToString());
                department_form = System.Convert.ToString(ListView2.Items[var2].SubItems[4].Text.ToString());
                position_form = System.Convert.ToString(ListView2.Items[var2].SubItems[5].Text.ToString());
                message_Form = System.Convert.ToString(ListView2.Items[var2].SubItems[6].Text.ToString());
                status_form = System.Convert.ToString(ListView2.Items[var2].SubItems[7].Text.ToString());
                id_form = System.Convert.ToString(ListView2.Items[var2].SubItems[8].Text.ToString());
                userIP_click = System.Convert.ToString(ListView2.Items[var2].SubItems[9].Text.ToString());
```

Basically, the codes here works like this: the program will get the data from my database and then add them to my Listview2.

(Also, can someone check if my adding items to listview2 will work? I can't run the program right now because I really have to do lots of re-coding. I'm migrating from VB.NET to C# WPF).

Going on: each variable, like userName_click will have the data from the 
listview2-row-VAR2 with columns 0 to 8.

I tried replacing the subitems[n] with binding names like User from -->
(new binding("user")) but it didn't work.

by the way, here is my XAML code in listview2.

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="-10,446,-22,-50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="702" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ClipToBounds="True">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{DynamicResource CustomHeaderStyle}">
                    <l:FixedWidthColumn Header="username" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding User}" FixedWidth="65"/>
                    <l:FixedWidthColumn Header="Host Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding hostNamedb}" FixedWidth="65"/>
                    <l:FixedWidthColumn Header="fullname" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding fullName}" FixedWidth="85"/>
                    <l:FixedWidthColumn Header="location" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding location}" FixedWidth="65"/>
                    <l:FixedWidthColumn Header="department" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding department}" FixedWidth="65"/>
                    <l:FixedWidthColumn Header="position" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding position}" FixedWidth="65"/>
                    <l:FixedWidthColumn Header="message" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding message}" FixedWidth="65"/>
                    <l:FixedWidthColumn Header="status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding status}" FixedWidth="65"/>
                    <l:FixedWidthColumn Header="id" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding id}" FixedWidth="65"/>
                    <l:FixedWidthColumn Header="ip" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ip}" FixedWidth="65"/>

                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not following, but since you know about binding I think you already know  that. I can not help you making your existing code work, but instead suggest the following: Use an observable collection to hold your DB-Objects with fields like user, hostNamedb...

```
public DbEntry(){
    user = SQLDataReader["User"].ToString();
    hostNamedb = SQLDataReader["hostNamedb"].ToString();
    fullName = SQLDataReader["fullName"].ToString();
    location = SQLDataReader["location"].ToString();
    ...
```

}

These will fill your observable collection. Next you bind to that collection via ItemsSource in your XAML.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DBObjectsCollection}">
```

Filling your variables with data is now only a matter of specifiying the index of the "row" from which to get the data, and getting the right field or property, e.g.

```
userName_click = DBObjectsCollection[2].user;
```

Mind you, this code will not work. This is only meant to be a basic pointer to how to solve your problem in WPF. There is already tons on information on WPF, but feel free to ask questions, should any arise.